# XAML ToggleButton change background image with isChecked={Binding xyz}

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm having the following working code in my app.xaml now...

```
<Style x:Key="likeActionButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="HoverBackground"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty = "Visibility">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty = "Visibility">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Image Width="25" Source="ms-appx:///Assets\ActionIcons\like-action.png"></Image>
                                    <Image x:Name="HoverBackground" Width="25" Source="ms-appx:///Assets\ActionIcons\like-action-onHover.png" Visibility="Collapsed"></Image>
                                    <Image x:Name="PressedBackground" Width="25" Source="ms-appx:///Assets\ActionIcons\like-action-on-pressed.png" Visibility="Collapsed"></Image>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

And I'm calling this template with:

```
<ToggleButton Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                          Style="{StaticResource likeActionButton}" 
                                          IsChecked="{Binding LikeState}"  
                                          Tapped="Favourite_Tapped"></ToggleButton>
```

The binding of the `LikeState` works not as perfect as I want it to be.

It's hard to explain, but I'll give it a try...

I can select and deselect the `ToggleButton` and the background image will always flip.
The binding behind the `LikeState` seems to work for the property but not for the image. This means when the data loads and the boolean `LikeState = true` the property `ToggleButton.IsChecked = true` but the background image is the image for `VisualState x:Name="Normal"`.

Again with other words...
I'm loading the data with `LikeState = true`. If I click the first time on the ToggleButton, the background image doesn't change, but the code-behind file executes the code for `isChecked = true`
Clicking the second time on the ToggleButton does change now the background image to `VisualState x:Name="Pressed"`

So what do i have to do to set the right background image in dependency to the dynamically filled property `isChecked={Binding LikeState}`

Cheers,

Chris

Comment: Try Mode=TwoWay in binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Mode=TwoWay` in binding. 
Since your changing bounded property value in code behind, to reflect that in view you have to give Mode as TwoWay

**Update**

I have checked your code. It just works fine without two way binding.

Use visual state **checked**

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                      </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty = "Visibility">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                           </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPointerOver">

                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPressed"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="CheckedDisabled">
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminatePointerOver"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminatePressed"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="IndeterminateDisabled">
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Hope your implementing INotifyPropertyChanged for the LikeState property so that initially it will be checked. If not please do the following. Here is what i did

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        bool likeState=true;
        public bool LikeState 
        {
            get { return likeState; }
            set
            {
                if(value!=likeState)
                {
                    value = likeState;
                    OnPropertyChanged("LikeState");
                }
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
           if(this.PropertyChanged!=null)
                this.PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        }
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
            LikeState = true;
            toggle.DataContext = this;

        }
}
```